# How to use substring method in javascript from the input strings?

Tags: javascript, html, substring

Could you share the solution of substring methods from the input string using HTML+Javascript ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" value="test"></input>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="testCode">Click</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("testCode");
  var res = substring(0, 5).value;
  document.write(res);}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substring will return part of the string. Also, add the `ID` on input field to get the value but rather using the button id itself. See the following snippet

```js
function myFunction() {
  const test = document.getElementById("testInput");
  var res = test.value.substr(0, 3);
  
  document.write(res);
  
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" value="test" id="testInput"></input>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="testCode">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`substring` should be called on string variable

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Like so

```
const test = document.getElementById('your-id')
test.value = test.value.substring(0, 6);
```